# Activate tropo application via email

Tags: sms, tropo

I'm trying to link Backback and Tropo to send reminders to groups.

Backpack can send reminders via email or SMS, and Tropo can receive messages via a custom SMS number; the problem is that Backback sends the SMS via email, and needs a provider. It can also be activated with a specific url and receives REST or JSON data.

Is there any way to activate a Tropo application using email or find out what provider setting I should use for Tropo?

ON TROPO:
Phone Numbers:
Voice & Messaging: (705) xxx-xxxx

Outbound Tokens:
Voice: ...
Messaging:  ...

Answer (score 0):

Tropo does not have an email gateway for receiving SMS. Applications that send SMS by email won't be able to send to Tropo.

One thing you could do is built a small catcher application that receives the REST call from backpack and then makes a REST call to Tropo to send the SMS. It would be sort of like a translator from Backpack's REST api to Tropo's.